# How to find the no. of employees department wise?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Lets say I have n documents whose document structure looks like this-

```
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dept1</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dept11</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dept12</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dep13</dept> </employee>  
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dep1n</dept> </employee>  

<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dept2</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dept21</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dept22</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dept23</dept> </employee>  
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>dept2n</dept> </employee>  

<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>deptn</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>deptn1</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>deptn2</dept> </employee>
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>deptn3</dept> </employee>  
<employee>  <name/>     <dob/>  .....   <dept>deptnn</dept> </employee>
```

And `dept1` is the parent. i.e. All dept with name like dept11,dept12,dept13...are subset of dept1. Similary `dept2` is the parent and all dept with the name like dept21,dept22,dept23 are subset of `dept2`.
I want to find the list of employees who belong to the main deptartment i.e. list of employees who belong to dept1,dept11,dept12 & so on, with the help of `Xquery` and `Marklogic` API's.
Hope you all understood the question.

Comment: If the amount of departments less than 10 (else i don't understand  how interpret 111 - 11-1 or 1-11), with Xath 1.0 you can for each department get  `count(//employee//dept[starts-with(.,'dept2')])`

Comment: the document count is n and there is no - symbol used. Its 11, 12, 13 etc.

Comment: @rishabhv66 The question was, if there are more then 10 departments, what would 'dept111' mean? *child no 1 of parent 'dept11'* or *child no 11 of parent 'dept1'*?

Comment: From my example it's clear there is no such thing as 111. Maximum it will be 1n where n is a number from [0-9].

Answer (score 3):

A solution that would scale better would make use of a range index on `dept`, a lexicon lookup with `cts:values` to get the unique values of `dept` with their frequencies. And then an ordinary loop through the values to aggregate frequencies with the parent department. Perhaps something like:

```
let $aggregates := map:map()
let $_ :=
  for $dept in cts:values(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("dept")))
  let $freq := cts:frequency($dept)
  let $parent := substring($dept, 1, 5)
  return map:put($aggregates, $parent, (map:get($aggregates, $parent), 0)[1] + $freq)
return $aggregates
```

To make it even easier, you could consider making parent department explicit by changing your XML to something like:

```
<dept>dept1</dept><sub-dept>dept11</sub-dept>
```

That way a `cts:values` on `dept` would immediately give the accurate frequency counts of the top-level departments, and a `cts:values` on `sub-dept` would give the same for sub-departments.

HTH!

Comment: could you explain what going on here - map:get($aggregates, $parent), 0)[1] + $freq) ?

Comment: `(map:get($aggregates, $parent), 0)[1]` looks if a value is known for key `$parent`. If not, it selects 0. In other languages you could write `map:get($aggregates, $parent) || 0`, but unfortunately not in XQuery. The `+ $freq`, just adds the frequency of the current dept to that of the parent, which gets saved using the `map:put`..

Answer (score 0):

For now I have found a solution. There can be a better way to achieve this, I am sure.

```
let $result := for $x in /doc/employee/dept[fn:starts-with(., "dept")] order by $x descending
                return $x
let $max := fn:codepoints-to-string(fn:string-to-codepoints($result[1])[5])
let $res := for $x in (1 to xs:integer($max))
              let $count := fn:count(/doc/employee/dept[fn:starts-with(., fn:concat("dept",xs:string($x)))])
              return (<doc><dept>dept{$x}</dept><count>{$count}</count></doc>)
return $res
```

The result would be like for example-

```
<doc>
  <dept>dept1</dept>
  <count>3</count>
</doc>
<doc>
  <dept>dept2</dept>
  <count>2</count>
</doc>
<doc>
  <dept>dept3</dept>
  <count>1</count>
</doc>
```